# how to strip out tags and style rules from Rails html

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to strip out style tags and the embedded css rules using sanitize. Like the following:

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize("<style> .emphasized { font-weight: bold } </style> hey <div class='emphasized'>watch out</div>",  tags: %w(strong b br p ul li em u))
=> " .emphasized { font-weight: bold }  hey watch out"
```

but giving me the css rule still. Would I have to use Nokogiri or something else or can sanitize handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to define a custom scrubber. For example

```rb
class MyScrubber < Rails::Html::PermitScrubber
  def initialize
    super
    self.tags = %w(strong b br p ul li em u)
  end

  def scrub(node)
    node.name == 'style' ? node.remove : super(node)
  end
end

ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize("<style> .emphasized { font-weight: bold } </style> hey <div class='emphasized'>watch out</div>",  scrubber: MyScrubber.new)
```